# Bootstrap Modal on non-bootstrap website

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to use a bootstrap modal as seen here:

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/

In the example modals. However my site uses 0 bootstrap resources (.css or .js).

**What is the simplest way i can go about adding bootstrap (both in UI and animation style) modals to my site?**

Just extract the bits needed from bootstrap.js and .css that are needed? Just wondering if there are other options.

Thank you.

Comment: You can [customize](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) your Bootstrap download so you don't have to manually extract the needed JS and CSS parts. You can copy/paste these into your current JS and CSS files, so you avoid including bootstrap.js and boostrap.css on their own, although this is a bad practice.

Comment: @Filly trying this with just the modals now, thanks i forgot about the customizer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its better to use the minified versions of the .js and .css files from the bootstrap bundle rather than bits and pieces of the files.

You can download it from : https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/releases/download/v3.1.1/bootstrap-3.1.1-dist.zip

Using modals is very simple after that: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Comment: that was my initial thought but there will be conflicts between the entire bootstrap bundle and my own css/js. :/